# This PHP if loop should be the most, strangest question here, but I do want to know

Tags: php

This first loop executes when $cnt=3 and the other other than $cnt=3.  Whatever the value of $cnt only the first loop executes whether $cnt=3 or $cnt==3.

```
$ary = explode(".", $string);
$cnt = count($ary);
if ($cnt="3") {
//executes when cnt=3
  $fnm = $d[0];
  $fnxt = $d[1].".".$d[2];
} else {
//executes when anything other than when cnt=3
   $fnm = $d[0];
   $fnxt = $d[1];
}
```

I might be missing something here, what exactly wrong here?

Thanks
Jean

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing an `=` sign on the comparison.  It should be:

```
if ($cnt == 3)
```

As it is, you're *assigning* 3 to `$cnt`, and since the assignment operator returns its value, the test becomes `if (3)`, which of course always succeeds.

NB: `count()` returns an integer, which is why my version above compares against `3` rather than `"3"`

Comment: Either way the second loop does not executes. give it a shot

Comment: Works for me.  http://pastie.org/pastes/1879031/text  The flaw must be somewhere else in your logic.

Comment: Yup, works for me too.  BTW, in your code above you've used `$d` but the actual array is `$ary` ?

Answer (score 5):

You are missing an "="

```
if ($cnt="3") {  // This is an assignment, which returns true.
```

This should be:

```
if ($cnt == "3") { // This is a comparison.
```

Comment: Works for me. http://pastie.org/pastes/1879031/text The flaw must be somewhere else in your logic.

Answer (score 1):

`$cnt="3"` assigns the value `"3"` to `$cnt`, and the expression as a whole evaluates to `"3"`, which is true, which causes the `if` block to always be executed.  In order to test whether `$cnt` is equal to `"3"`, use the `==` operator: `$cnt == "3"`.